# scala pattern matching on value in sequence of strings

Tags: scala, design-patterns, sequence, matching

variable someKey can be either "a", "b" or "c".

I can do this:

```
someKey match {
    case "a" => someObjectA.execute()
    case "b" => someOther.execute()
    case "c" => someOther.execute()
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown")
}
```

how can I compress this pattern matching so I can check if someKey with e.g. Seq("b", "c") and if it is in the sequence then replace two lines of pattern match with one?

EDIT:

```
someKey match {
        case "a" => someObjectA.execute()
        case someKey if Seq("b","c").contains(someKey) => someOther.execute()
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown")
    }
```

Comment: You can use `case k if seq.contains(k)` also, I would use a **Set** instead of a **Seq**. You could also have a **Map** from key to computation or to a common type which has `execute`.

Comment: This is more like a switch case statement not pattern matching, but anyway, I do not completely understand what you mean, but if you want to match the elements inside a Seq using the same functionality, you can turn this code into a function, and then pass the function as `map` argument inside `seq.map(function)`

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez yes, Set does the job. TY

Comment: @AminMal see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have "or" in the `case` clause:

```
someKey match {
    case "a" => someObjectA.execute()
    case "b"|"c" => someOther.execute()
    case _ => ???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, I'd probably go to

```
// likely in some companion object so these get constructed once
val otherExecute = { () => someOther.execute() }
val keyedTasks = Map(
  "a" -> { () => someObjectA.execute() },
  "b" -> otherExecute,
  "c" -> otherExecute
)

// no idea on the result type of the execute calls?  Unit?
def someFunction(someKey: String) = {
  val resultOpt = keyedTasks.get(someKey).map(_())

  if (resultOpt.isDefined) resultOpt.get
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown")
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `if` I would use `getOrElse(throw) ` or maybe a `fold` if you want to do something with the value.

Comment: I'm going for didactic clarity here... given my druthers, I'd model this in the type system.